# How do I avoid tank abuses?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

As time passes by, tanks are becoming more and more of an annoyance **for me** in GTAV Online.

Before the last update, people in tanks at least paid for my car insurance, now I'm driving around, minding my own business when **BAM**, my adder gets blown to pieces and I'm the one to pay 12,5k for its insurance.

Being a level 52, I'm still unable to reach the right guns for the job, so I was wondering:

How do I get rid of tank with grenades and sticky bombs being my most disruptive devices?

Comment: The grand-theft-auto-5 tag is for the offline game.  Since you're asking about the online one, the tag is completely unneccessary.

Comment: Fair enough, @Frank.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's costumary on StackExchange sites to coment on such situations instead of just flaming.

Comment: Comments on *any* downvote are completely optional.  Always has been, always will be.  It wasn't me, for the record, but asking for reasoning on a single downvote is counterproductive; it might attract more.  Downvotes are *not* personal.  It is done on the content.  Not on you.

Comment: Costumary <> obligatory. Also counterproductive is being so hostile towards new users.

Comment: I'm not being hostile whatsoever.  I'm pointing out that downvotes with comments are not how the system is designed, and if someone had wanted to comment, they would have.

Comment: Costumary <> Customary

Comment: Thank you @Archer for your most interesting and useful input.

Comment: It's a pleasure :)

Comment: @Doc Just to be sure we are at the same page, you do know that <> means not equal, or in other words, not the same, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To destroy a tank go off the radar and put 5 sticky bombs on it. Detonate them and **BAM!**

This works best when the tank is parked and I would suggest be in a civilian car as they won't expect you! If they are parked and do not see you why not steal it?

Comment: Don't just put sticky bombs on it. Put them on the rear grille. The tank can withstand more explosives from the front and sides, and the grille is where the engine is, a "weak spot".

Answer (score 0):

I'm level 25 I can throw sticky grades on the tank and detonate them or get an attack chopper from my friend and that's how I kill tanks

Answer (score -1):

if I were you I would go on passive mode an they cant shot you but they can run you over so just run an get up high.